# Cannot use project function to reproject SpatVector to EPSG:3035

Tags: r, spatial, terra

I have a SpatVector containing occurrence records coordinates and a SpatRaster Corine land cover layer and would like to count the number of records in each land cover layer cell. However, before I can do this, I need to reproject the SpatVector to match the projection and extent of the SpatRaster, which is EPSG: 3035.

I've tried using the below code but encounter the error `Error: [project] input crs is not valid`

```
#The below SpatVector is just a reproducible snipped of what I am working with
 #in my script I am working with occurrence records downloaded from GBIF
occurrence <- terra::vect(cbind(c(5.73582, 5.673900, 5.770425),
                                c(58.79926, 58.73660, 58.70576))

proj_occ <- terra::project(occurrence, "epsg:3035")
```

This same line of code worked as intended when I re-projected the country shapefile (downloaded in R using the geodata::gadm() function).

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I am also open to suggestions as to how I can calculate the number of occurrences in the cells using a method other than rasterize(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the crs of the input data. For example like this

```
library(terra)
occurrence <- terra::vect(cbind(c(5.73582, 5.673900, 5.770425),
                                c(58.79926, 58.73660, 58.70576)), 
                                crs="+proj=longlat")

proj_occ <- terra::project(occurrence, "epsg:3035")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fix! I've now been able to do what I wanted!